# Devise in a mounted engine uses wrong url for a 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-engines, warden

I'm using Devise in a mounted engine (`my_engine`) in my Rails application (`my_application`). This works quite well, but there's still one problem: if a user tries to access a restricted resource (i.e. a page that's protected with a `before_filter authenticate_user!`) Devise/Warden generates a 401 response and redirects to the sign_in url. Unfortunately this sign_in url is not prefixed with the engine's mount path.

So my problem ist that the url that Devise uses for forwarding the browser to the sign_in page is wrong.

The engine's `routes.rb` file is...

```
My_Engine::Engine.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, {
                       class_name: "My_Engine::User",
                       module: :devise,
                       controllers: {registrations: 'my_engine/users/registrations'}
                     }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'users/registrations/after_sign_up/:id' => "users/registrations#after_sign_up", as: :after_sign_up
    get 'users/registrations/after_confirm/:id' => "users/registrations#after_confirm", as: :after_confirm
  end
end
```

The generated routes are all ok:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern Controller#Action
  my_engine      /my_engine       My_Engine::Engine

Routes for My_Engine::Engine:
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                         devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                         devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                        devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                        devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                    devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                   devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                        devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                        devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                          my_engine/users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                 my_engine/users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                         my_engine/users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                            my_engine/users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                                 my_engine/users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                 my_engine/users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                 my_engine/users/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)                    devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)                    devise/confirmations#show
           after_sign_up GET    /users/registrations/after_sign_up/:id(.:format) my_engine/users/registrations#after_sign_up
           after_confirm GET    /users/registrations/after_confirm/:id(.:format) my_engine/users/registrations#after_confirm
```

Now when I access a protected resource, Devise generates a 401 and redirects to the sign_in path, but the url is not prefixed with '/my_engine`.

It uses `/users/sign_in`, but it should use `/my_engine/users/sign_in`.

```
19:41:11 web.1  | Started GET "/my_engine/users/edit" for ::1 at 2015-03-09 19:41:11 +0100
19:41:11 web.1  | Processing by My_Engine::Users::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
19:41:11 web.1  | Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
19:41:11 web.1  | 
19:41:11 web.1  | 
19:41:11 web.1  | Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2015-03-09 19:41:11 +0100
19:41:11 web.1  | 
19:41:11 web.1  | ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_in"):
19:41:11 web.1  |   actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
```

Has anyone encountered this before ? It seems that there is a related problem with omniauthenticable in engines, but I'm not sure if they share the same cause.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated, you can set whatever path you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Ativ's answer, which solved my problem.

In short, I had to add a Devise::FailureApp to the engine's lib folder, tell Devise to use it and load it upon start.

See [github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated) for details.

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly this but I keep getting a "uninitialized constant CustomFailure (NameError)", can you post your engine setup for loading the failure app ? I added this to my `engine.rb` file : `config.autoload_paths << File.expand_path('../../lib/devise', __FILE__)` without success.